# Where are the Fiesta servers located?

Tags: fiesta-online

The login screen only shows the server list. No ping, no status, just population.

I have found GoldICQ's list where they show WHERE are the servers located. I.E.: US, EU, DE, FR, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Outspark's central US web server is located in San Francisco, CA: http://pezis.com/outspark.com

They also have several other websites for different languages and countries. For example, their German website:  http://fiesta-online.de.w3spy.net/

It's reasonable to assume that the game servers are located in the appropriate countries (IE, German Game Server is most likely located in Germany).

An old news article about it : http://www.fiestafan.com/forums/showthread.php?t=21719